# Pivot table showing 0 values

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Oi,

I have this pivot table i'd like to refresh. After clicking the "Refresh" button, every values changes to 0, while in reality it should show another amount.
When doubleclicking the 0 values, i see that the values that should be shown are stored as "text".

Any fix for this?

Comment: store the values as number, not text?

Comment: They're stored ok in the original file ( Its a Pivot table linked to another Excel file)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better way, but this is the way I'm fixing it.

Select (from the source) the column that is stored as "text",

Go to [Data] -> [Text to Columns] -> [Next] -> [Next]

and then select (o) General and click [Finish]

Answer (score 0):

Just posting here just in case someone solve same problem. I experienced this same behavior this week and the source of my issue was in **Power Query**. Be mindful of the data types used in your transformations. In turns out, using data type as `Int64.Type` while dividing may return as zeros in your pivot table. Changing the type to `decimal` solved the issue. [Here's Microsoft's documentation on Data Types in models and how they behave with operands](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-types-in-data-models-e2388f62-6122-4e2b-bcad-053e3da9ba90). Apologies for the lack of details, hoping this will save someone some agony one day.